# Cannot read property of 'length' and I'm not sure why

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, typeerror

I'm getting this error when I click on an element of my HTML page that supposed to load a timetable of sorts.

```
example.js:26 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (example.js:26)
    at HTMLElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:1623)
    at HTMLElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:1585)
(anonymous) @ example.js:26
dispatch @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:1623
q.handle @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:1585
```

Here's the javascript portion.

```
    $(function () { //when the DOM is ready
    var times; //declare global variable
    $.ajax({ //set up request
        beforeSend: function (xhr) { //before requesting data
            if (xhr.overrideMimeType) { //if supported
                xhr.overrideMimeType("application/json"); // set MIME to prevent errors
            }
        }
    });
    //funciton that collect data from the json file
    function loadTimetable() { //decalre function
        $.getJSON('data/example.json') //try to collect json data
            .done(function (data) { //if succesful
                times = data; //store in variable
            }).fail(function () { //if a problem: show message
                $('#event').html('Sorry! we couldnt load your time table at the moment');
            });
    }
    loadTimetable(); //call the function

    //CLICK ON TEH EVENT TO LOAD A TIME TABLE
    $('#content').on('click', '#event a', function (e) { //user clicks on place
        e.preventDefault(); //prevent loading page
        var loc = this.id.toUpperCase(); //get value of id attr
        var newContent = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < times[loc].length; i++) { // loop through sessions
            newContent += '<li><span class = "time">' + times[loc][i].time + '</span>';
            newContent += '<a href = "descriptions.html#';
            newContent += times[loc][i].title.replace(/ /g, '-') + '">';
            newContent += times[loc][i].title + '</a></li>';
        }
        $('#sessions').html('<ul>' + newContent + '</ul>'); // Display Time
        $('#event a.current').removeClass('current'); // update selected link
        $(this).addClass('current');
        $('#details').text('');
    });

    //CLICK ON A SESSION TO LEAD THE DESCRIPTION
    $('#content').on('click', '#sessions li a', function (e) { //click on session
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent loading
        var fragment = this.href; //title is in href
        fragment = fragment.replace('#', ' #'); //Add Space before #
        $('#details').load(fragment); //to load info
        $('#sessions a.current').removeClass('current'); //update selected
    });

    //CLICK ON PRIMARY NAVIGATION
    $('nav a').on('click', function (e) { //click on nav
        e.preventDefault(); //prevent loading
        var url = this.href; //get UR: to load
        $('nav a.current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
        $('#container').remove(); //remove old
        $('#content').load(url + ' #container').hide().fadeIn('slow'); // add new
    });
});
```

I think there's definitely something wrong in the way I'm referencing other files in my project folder because I'm working off a similar project that works fine but I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: it looks like, that `times[loc]` is `undefined`.

Comment: Which of these lines is line 26?

Comment: The error is saying that the variable `times` is not defined (when you refer to it in your for loop). Have you defined that somewhere?

Comment: @SunilD. Well, `times` most likely *is* defined, but `loc` most likely is not a valid index of `times`. If `times` weren't defined, the error would be about trying to pass an index to `undefined`.

Answer (score 4):

The key to fixing the problem is reading the portion of the error message that you didn't post in your title:

*Cannot read property 'length' **of undefined***

This isn't complaining about the `length` property, per se. It's telling you that `times[loc]` isn't defined. So, you need to verify that `times` is, in fact, an array and that `loc` evaluates to a valid index of that array.

Comment: the thing is, it's defined as a global variable at the beginning of my code, I've included the whole thing in my post now. I think it's not reading my .json file and I'm not sure why.

Comment: @Adamwuh Well, your variable isn't global - - it's scoped to the `document.ready` function. However, it's possible that you are trying to access `times[loc]` before the AJAX call has returned, in which case, the `times` variable would not have been initialized yet. I would take the entire `click` event assignment function and place it into the `done` callback, so that you know that you aren't using `times` until after it's been set. Also, I would log `times` in the `done` handler to ensure that it is getting the value you expect.